# how can I make an object from string contains printed object

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, object

I have some code:

Test Controller:

```
        Class test extends CI_Controller{
            public function print_object(){
                 $x = (object) array('a'=>'A', 'b'=>'B', 'C');
                 echo '<pre>'.print_r($x, true).'</pre>';
            }
        }
```

Test2 Controller:

```
        Class test2 extends CI_Controller{
            public function get_printed_object(){
                 $url = "http://localhost/project/test/print_object";
                 (object) $str = file_get_contents($url);
                 echo $str->a; //won't make it. resulting error
            }
        }
```

the line

```
echo $str->a;
```

was resulted a warning : Trying to get property of non-object

Is it possible for me to re-make the $x object that was printed to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue that you have is that `file_get_contents` returns a string with the output of the url. `$str` is therefore a string only and even the cast won't change that.

If you want to convert it to an object then you can [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) (or serialize) and output that in test. test2 would then have to `json_decode($str)` to recreate the object.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the native `serialize()` and `unserialize()` functions.
by serializing an object you will obtain a json-like (its not json, but looks like) string with all the information. When you unserialize, you obtain a clone of the serialized object, and can access its methods and properties in a normal way.

check out the php manual for this functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

and this last page for a cool example:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php